# reduce_sum by certain dimension

Tags: tensorflow

I have two embeddings tensor `A` and `B`, which looks like

```
[
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1,1]
]
```

and

```
[
  [0,0,0],
  [1,1,1]
]
```

what I want to do is calculate the L2 distance `d(A,B)` element-wise.

First I did a `tf.square(tf.sub(lhs, rhs))` to get

```
[
  [1,1,1],
  [0,0,0]
]
```

and then I want to do an element-wise reduce which returns

```
[
  3,
  0
]
```

but `tf.reduce_sum` does not allow my to reduce by row. Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `reduction_indices` argument with a value of 1, eg.:

```
tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( tf.sub( lhs, rhs) ), 1 )
```

That should produce the result you're looking for. [Here is the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum) on `reduce_sum()`.

Answer (score 5):

According to [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops/reduction#reduce_sum), `reduce_sum` function which takes four arguments.

```
tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor, axis=None, keep_dims=False, name=None, reduction_indices=None).
```

But `reduction_indices` has been deprecated. Better to use axis instead of. If the axis is not set, reduces all its dimensions.

As an example,this is taken from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops/reduction#reduce_sum),

```
# 'x' is [[1, 1, 1]
#         [1, 1, 1]]
tf.reduce_sum(x) ==> 6
tf.reduce_sum(x, 0) ==> [2, 2, 2]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1) ==> [3, 3]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1, keep_dims=True) ==> [[3], [3]]
tf.reduce_sum(x, [0, 1]) ==> 6
```

Above requirement can be written in this manner,

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.array([[1,7,1],[1,1,1]])
b = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])

xtr = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 3])
xte = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 3])

pred = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(xtr, xte)),1)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    nn_index = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={xtr: a, xte: b})
    print nn_index
```